# Trigger for new complaint managing system

Tags: trigger

I am trying to make a trigger for Complaint case management i want if a case is lodged via web to case or email to case it should find the Contact details of the related person in Salesforce if available.

Please guide if this is the right way:

```
List<Contact> c = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Name = :YOUR_NAME   AND   (Email=:YOUR_EMAIL OR MobilePhone = :YOUR_MOBILE) ] ;

Boolean contactAlreadyExists = false ;

if(c.size() > 0)
{
     contactAlreadyExists = true;
```

Comment: Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: List at line 1 column 0

Comment: What appears above is a "block of code" that could be used in a class or trigger. What object do you want your trigger to operate on? Do you want the trigger to fire, before insertion or after insertion, before update or after update, or before/after delete? These are all things you need to know when defining a trigger and writing the code. I refer you to the [Apex Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.htm).